# SharePoint Site not picking the Last name, First name functionality?

Tags: 2010, site

SharePoint Site not picking the Last name, First name functionality on Home Page Header which is default functionality of SharePoint, Instead its fetching First Name then last name.

It’s fetching the data from AD – using User Profile Service which is configured in a way,

It seems User Profile is configured in a way that first Name then Last Name? Any thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome.ascx control which you are talking about shows users' display name which comes from AD. If you want to change it, go to AD Users and Computers, click on account, in General tab change Display name and run profile sync again.

Answer (score 0):

The Welcome menu is actual a User Control (welcome.ascx) located in the default location _controlTemplates physical location on your SharePoint servers. Basically, one could customize that menu, which in turn would apply across the Whole Farm.

Wictor Willen actually has a nice write-up on is available here http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Having-fun-with-the-SharePoint-Welcomeascx-control.aspx